# How can I intercept touches on a marker in Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am new to the Google Maps SDK for iOS. When a user clicks on a marker, instead of showing the default info window with a title and snippet, I would like to direct them somewhere else in my app (such as a modal view controller). I have searched through the header files and online and I can't seem to find anything relating to touch events on markers. Does anyone have suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe what you want is to add the delegate and override the `didTapMarker` method

```
/**
 * Called after a marker has been tapped.
 *
 * @param mapView The map view that was pressed.
 * @param marker The marker that was pressed.
 * @return YES if this delegate handled the tap event, which prevents the map
 *         from performing its default selection behavior, and NO if the map
 *         should continue with its default selection behavior.
 */
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker;
```

Comment: I think the method has been changed a bit 
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
Second parameter now is a pointer to an instance of GMSMarker class.