# How to hide current point to replace custom mark

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a question about how to hide current point (blue dot) to replace custom mark. The platform is implemented on iOS and the Google Maps SDK for iOS API.

The hide method are as following:

```
mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO;
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
```

The question is that if I hide the current point, the event of "TapMyLocationButton" will not trigger.

How to hide the blue point and trigger the method.

```
- (BOOL)didTapMyLocationButtonForMapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView {
    NSLog(@"button click");
    return YES;
}
```

The code of custom icon:

```
GMSMarker *pointMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:newLocation.coordinate];
pointMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"currentLocationIcon"];

pointMarker.map = mapView;
```

Comment: Can't you use the tap event for custom markers?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057381/how-can-i-intercept-touches-on-a-marker-in-google-maps-sdk-for-ios.

Comment: No,we need hide the current point and use the custom icon replace blue point.But when I hide the blue point(mylocationEnabled=NO),the didTapMyLocationButton method was not trigger. We need click the myLocationButton(the button default position is below and right on the google map) to set the current latitude and longitude for the our custom icon.Now my question is when I hide the blue point,the myLocationButton was not triggle,that to cause I cant't set now position to my custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

On Tap.

mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
then repress location button.
then set  mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO;